# requires newer sdk level message when installing my app

Tags: android, sdk, google-play

I've recently made an android app and published it to the google play store. The problem is, people can download the app just fine, but when the device tries to install the app a "requires newer sdk level" message pops up. I have tried downloading it on many devices but end up with the same message.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are min & target sdk in your manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your Manifest sdk version to a version that is in your device.

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`